# f# assembly metadata not updated in visual studio

Tags: f#, metadata, visual-studio-2015

This is a possible bug in Visual Studio 2015 (and maybe earlier versions?), just want to check it here first because I didn't find any similar issues while googling it.

I have a solution with a C# console app and an F# library which is used by the console app.

In the F# library I have defined a class with some members, and I change the members. While Intellisense in the C# editor correctly reflects changes in the F# library, the metadata of the F# assembly is not being updated. I have tried to clean, rebuild, re-add the assembly reference, but the only solution is to reopen solution or restart visual studio.

What is wrong here?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: You mean the metadata you see when hitting F12, correct? If so, that's my problem as well and I don't know how to fix it.